# JQuery's $ function for PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm wondering that if there's something like JQuery's $('element.selector') implemented for PHP?

When I CURL and I got HTML codes from the remote site, I'd like to select only the tags I want before I send out to my HTML.

Thanks

Comment: You are looking for "phpQuery".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or perhaps Querypath (http://querypath.org/)?  Just read about it yesterday and it looks kind of cool.

Answer (score 14):

The [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) has a similar functionality:

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: LOL I reversed my opinion when i noticed the download link to dom parser.  Excuse me ;-)  Thanks for showing me HTML DOM Parser even tho i handle nothing but XHTML these days and just use DOM.

Comment: DOMDocument / DOMXPath is _extremely_ faster, implemented at C level, and it can equally deal with malformed HTML, maybe even better. Writing some helper functions altering 'jquery'/ 'css' selectors in XPath is not that hard.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ctx = xpath_new_context($doc); 
$xpath_nodes = xpath_eval($ctx, "//some_element");
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but it assumes the developer has written compliant and well formed xml for their html output, which I've found is rarely the case unless there is strict enforcement of it within the development cycle (which again is rare).

Comment: I used to run bad code through the tidy extension.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use server-side javascript. Haven't done that myself yet, though.